# Ubuntu server doesnt resolve correctly on home network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, samba, dns

I'm having an irritating networking issue on my ubuntu server (16.04 LTS). When I try to ssh into it from my ubuntu laptop I get "could not resolve hostname HOSTNAME: Name or service not known". SSH with the server's IP address works just fine.

Trying user@hostname from any windows computer works. Trying it from an ubuntu VM running within windows doesnt. Samba also works with the hostname, TS3 only with IP.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Relevant data:

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       hostname

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

/etc/networking/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ifconfig

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 94:de:80:20:5c:b8
      inet Adresse:192.168.0.28  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      inet6-Adresse: fe80::96de:80ff:fe20:5cb8/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:17133 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:2123 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
      RX-Bytes:7313948 (7.3 MB)  TX-Bytes:227844 (227.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
      RX-Pakete:265 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
      TX-Pakete:265 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1
      RX-Bytes:20889 (20.8 KB)  TX-Bytes:20889 (20.8 KB)
```

Comment: who is your DNS server? is it HOSTNAME?

Comment: Nope, my home router, a piece of crap called TC7200 (cable modem). But the router's DHCP site shows the correct IP and the corresponding host name.